# how to match a column of a file 1 to text of another file 2 then if it matches print file 2

Tags: shell-script, command-line, pattern-matching

File 1

```
Name,TaxID,Lineage,Count,Proportion_All(%),Proportion_Classified(%)
Acaryochloris marina,155978,Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;;Synechococcales;Acaryochloridaceae;Acaryochloris,4,0.000218669,0.00120249
Anabaena cylindrica,1165,Bacteria;Cyanobacteria;;Nostocales;Nostocaceae;Anabaena,9,0.000492005,0.00270561
```

File 2

```
Object_ID, Length, Assignment
NODE_1_length_501653_cov_19.284,501653,1727163
NODE_2_length_458856_cov_17.1812,458856,374606
NODE_3_length_369230_cov_19.3769,369230,1727163
NODE_4_length_342860_cov_16.7318,342860,83263
NODE_5_length_301494_cov_19.1256,301494,1727163
NODE_6498_length_5833_cov_14.8079,5833,155978
NODE_6499_length_5833_cov_4.85133,5833,NA
NODE_6500_length_5831_cov_23.1697,5831,553814
NODE_6501_length_5831_cov_22.403,5831,795665
```

Output

```
Object_ID, Length, Assignment
NODE_6498_length_5833_cov_14.8079,5833,155978
```

ALl values in second column of File 1 matches the text in the very last array of File 2, if found, print File 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {TaxID[$2]=1; next} FNR==1 || $NF in TaxID' File1 File2
Object_ID, Length, Assignment
NODE_6498_length_5833_cov_14.8079,5833,155978
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THIS ONE!!!! I was able to sort all the ones I need.